# PHP echo variable no funciona en jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, variables

estuve leyendo por stackoverflow en inglés la manera de recibir en jQuery el valor de una variable PHP y encontré esta forma:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".topic").click(function () {
        var postId = "<?php echo $post[\'id\']; ?>";
        alert(postId);
    });                         
});
```

Y al momento de ejecutar el script, en la alerta me aparece literal el código PHP en vez de ejecutar el echo y mostrar el valor.
¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?
Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código debe estar embebido en tu html, generalmente en un archivo con extencion php y ser interpetado por php.

Algo asi:

```
<?php 
$post['id'] = 10; 
?>
<html>
 <head>
     <script>


        $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".topic").click(function () {
            var postId = "<?php echo $post['id']; ?>";
            alert(postId);
            });                         
        });

     </script>
 </head>
 <body>

 </body>
</html>
```

[Aquí un ejemplo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1dc5004e09c79edd0c543a7ac07ba308e99bea07)

De todas maneras te recomendaría manejar un único objeto javascript donde guardes todas las variables que cargues desde el servidor la primera ves.

```
<script>
 var datosDeInicio = <?php echo json_encode($miVariable); ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: Por supuesto que está dentro de <html> y en un archivo php

Comment: Checa el enlace no hay pierde

Answer (score 3):

creo que podrias evitar el uso de backslash "\" porque esos servirian si estuvieras utilizando comillas dobles dentro de otras comillas dobles " \" ", en este caso como usas comillas simples dentro de comillas dobles " ' " no es necesario.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".topic").click(function () {
        var postId = "<?php echo $post['id']; ?>";
        alert(postId);
    });                         
});
```

y solo para estar seguro, tu archivo si es .php y existe la variable $post['id']? seria de gran ayuda si compartieras mas parte de tu codigo y mayor informacion del problema.

Comment: Yo lo puse como $post[\'id\']; porque el script está dentro de un echo de PHP y estoy usando apostrofes para el echo, comillas para la variables y no me quedó de otra más que usar tal signo.
Mi archivo si es PHP y si existe dicha variable.

Comment: @MauricioPortilla Los backslash sobran totalmente en tu código. No estaría de más que verificaras que `$post['id']` existe, usando una traza por ejemplo.

Comment: No estoy mostrando todo el código, igual no afecta en nada. Ya verifiqué y sí existe porque lo estoy tomando de un foreach, incluso lo puse como valor en un campo de texto y muestra perfectamente el valor de la variable.

Answer (score 0):

@MalCam esta en lo cierto, si quieres utilizar variables de php en JavaScript, tendras que procesar el archivo en PHP... es decir, el JS se debe encontrar dentro de un archivo de .php